# Cannot retrieve http sites when using OpenVPN, but https sites work just fine. Why?

Tags: iptables, http, openvpn, https

I am using a VPN provider that uses OpenVPN. I don´t wont any other traffic leave my computer so I have set up my iptables like this:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 

### Inbound rules
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

### Outbound rules
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

I am just permitting OpenVPN traffic and DNS lookup (for the OpenVPN connection).
The connection goes just fine.

The probem occurs when I try to visit `http` sites. The connection times out. But `https` works!
If I do `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` everything works just perfect!

I have checked with Wireshark when using both `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` and `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` but I cannot see anything that differs, except that when using DROP, `http` sites cannot be fetched.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to double-test other elements of your rules - it looks to me that they don't accept either HTTP or HTTPS traffic - I wonder if while fiddling with the rules you added (and possibly subsequently removed) HTTPS traffic - leaving the "ESTABLISHED" connection in-tact and giving you a false reading.   You can test this theory by using iptables -vnL and watching how the counters for the rules change when you do various requests.

I expect you need to add

```
> iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
> iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Or, if you want a more generic solution that allows all your traffic down the tunnel to work

```
> iptables -A output -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thankyou! I didn´t think about the tun and tap interfaces. I am now permitting traffic through tun and it now works!